# jQuery each and attaching click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to achieve the condition click event on each class element. This is my code.

```js
//Edit input field
$('.js-edit, .js-save').each(function(index) {
  $(this).on("click", function() {
    var $form = $(this).closest('form');
    $form.toggleClass('is-readonly is-editing');
    var isReadonly = $form.hasClass('is-readonly');
    $form.find('input').prop('disabled', isReadonly);
  });
});
```

```css
form.is-readonly .btn-save {
  display: none;
}

form.is-readonly input[disabled],
form.is-readonly textarea[disabled] {
  cursor: text;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-color: transparent;
  outline-color: transparent;
  box-shadow: none;
}

form.is-editing .btn-edit {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="is-readonly" action="" method="post">
  <input type="text" class="form-control is-disabled" value="40" disabled>
  <button type="button" class="btn-edit js-edit">Edit</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn-save js-save">Save</button>

  <input type="text" class="form-control is-disabled" value="38" disabled>
  <button type="button" class="btn-edit js-edit">Edit</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn-save js-save">Save</button>

</form>
```

I have two input fields, at the moment click event making both field editable, i want it work separately for each field.

I hope you guys understand my question.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want to achieve?

I wrapped each field and its corresponding buttons in a div and changed the script a bit to match the new HTML.

```js
//Edit input field
$('.js-edit, .js-save').each(function(index) {
  $(this).on("click", function() {
    var $group = $(this).closest('.group');
    $group.toggleClass('is-readonly is-editing');
    var isReadonly = $group.hasClass('is-readonly');
    $group.find('input').prop('disabled', isReadonly);
  });
});
```

```css
.group.is-readonly .btn-save {
  display: none;
}

.group.is-readonly input[disabled],
.group.is-readonly textarea[disabled] {
  cursor: text;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-color: transparent;
  outline-color: transparent;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.group.is-editing .btn-edit {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="post">
  <div class="group is-readonly">
   <input type="text" class="form-control is-disabled" value="40" disabled>
   <button type="button" class="btn-edit js-edit">Edit</button>
   <button type="button" class="btn-save js-save">Save</button>
  </div>

  <div class="group is-readonly">
    <input type="text" class="form-control is-disabled" value="38" disabled>
    <button type="button" class="btn-edit js-edit">Edit</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn-save js-save">Save</button>
  </div>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple attach the events separately:

```
$(document).on('click', '.js-edit', function(){
  console.log('Coming from Edit Button')
});
$(document).on('click', '.js-save', function(){
  console.log('Coming from SaveButton')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You set class for form element and it's wrong. you should set class for input parent (like container class)

```js
$('.js-edit, .js-save').on("click", function() {
  var $form = $(this).closest('form');
  var container = $(this).closest('.container');
  container.toggleClass('is-readonly is-editing');
  container.find('input').prop('disabled', $form.hasClass('is-readonly'));
});
```

```css
.container.is-readonly .btn-save {
  display: none;
}

.container.is-editing .btn-edit {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="post">
  <div class="container is-readonly">
    <input type="text" class="form-control is-disabled" value="40" disabled>
    <button type="button" class="btn-edit js-edit">Edit</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn-save js-save">Save</button>
  </div>
  <div class="container is-readonly">
    <input type="text" class="form-control is-disabled" value="38" disabled>
    <button type="button" class="btn-edit js-edit">Edit</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn-save js-save">Save</button>
  </div>
</form>
```